# Django DetailView queryset returns an empty list

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

DetailView queryset returns on full name which I suspect is coming from the model's `__str__` method.

Models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  ...

class Employee(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  ...
```

NOTE: the user == Profile pk in Employee model
View:

```
class EmpDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'users/emp_detail.html'
    model = Employee
    context_object_name = 'employee'
```

I tried this and it gets me what I need but the id is hard coded in, I don't have access to kwargs:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        employee = Employee.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, id="1").values('full_name', 'val2', 'val3', ... ) 
        return employee
```

Then I tried this but it returns an empty list.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmpDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        pk_= self.kwargs.get("id")
        context['employee'] = Employee.objects.filter(pk=pk_).values('full_name', 'val2', 'val3', ... ) 
        return context
```

How do I make a query in DetailView and pass it to template?

Comment: You have, it is in `self.kwargs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried this and it gets me what I need but the id is hard coded in, I don't have access to `kwargs`.

You can access the URL kwargs with `self.kwargs`, so for example:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return Employee.objects.get(
        user=self.request.user,
        pk=self.kwargs['id']
    )
```

Please do *not* use [**`.values(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values). This will erode the logical model layer. You should only use `.values(…)` in certain use cases, for example when you want to `GROUP BY` a certain field. If the number of columns is large, you can still use [**`.only(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only) to limit bandwidth.

For a `DetailView`, you do not need to filter on the `id` yourself, you can let Django do that for you. You can limit the items that are owned by the user by overriding the [**`.get_queryset(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset):

```
class EmpDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'users/emp_detail.html'
    model = Employee
    context_object_name = 'employee'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'id'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            user=self.request.user
        )
```

By specifying the [**`pk_url_kwarg`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg) you can let Django filter the primary key itself.

You can obtain the profile attached to the user with:

```
{{ user.profile }}
```

So if the `Profile` has an `ImageField` named `image` for example, you can obtain the media url with:

```
<img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
```

of course you will need to configure Django to [*serve media files during development* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development). In production, you will need to configure the webserver (like Apache or Nginx )to serve media files.

Comment: I get "TypeError at /1/ 'Employee' object is not iterable"

Comment: @KuyatehYankz: since this is a *single* object, you can not `{% for ... in employee %}`, `employee` is an `Employee`, so in your template, you just render this like for example `{{ employee.full_name }}`.

Comment: This is so elegant, how can I query a second model in the view?

Comment: @KuyatehYankz: normally a `DetailView` is meant to show the details of one object. Exactly what object do you want to display? How is it related to the `Employee` object?

Comment: I want to list employers name, address and logo from Profile model

Comment: But how is the `Employee` related to the `Profile` model, is there a `ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField`, etc. from `Employee` to `Profile` or vice versa. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64188278/edit) the question with the relevant models?